# Azure DevOps Branch Policy: How to resolve a required review from id to user?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I get the policy configuration for required reviewers there is a list of ids (looking like guids).

Where the required reviewer is a group I can match this with the results of getting Graph-Groups-List.

But when the reviewer is a specific user, and that user is a Windows (Live) account the result of Graph-Users-List does not contain the id from the policy. (AAD and VSTS accounts do have a guid, but I don't have a sample policy to check if they would match).

All the user lookup APIs are based on storage id or descriptor, not anything that looks like a guid (and I've just tried a few<sup>[1]</sup> passing the id from the policy).

What API can get a user's details given the id from the list of required reviewers?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The documentation is, in places, not consistent between reference and examples, so worth a try :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [User Identities api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) does a lookup by the same id that the policy uses.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?identityIds={UserId}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0
```